# Unable to connect to Meteor WebSocket using Android-DDP

Tags: android, meteor, websocket

I am trying to connect to my meteor application which runs at `192.168.207.84:3000` using [Android-DDP](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP):

```
// created an websocket connection

mMeteor = new Meteor(this, "ws://192.168.207.84:3000/");
```

I'm getting the following error:

> WebSocketConnection: fail connection [code = 3, reason = WebSockets connection lost

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"ws://192.168.207.84:3000/websocket"`?

Comment: i think websocket is their path but tried it too ...didnt worked

Comment: Can the phone access the application at this IP address. e.g, using the browser?

Comment: "http://192.168.207.84:3000" is working fine on phone and the meteor application is getting loaded but "ws://192.168.207.84:3000/" is not

Comment: found the address?

Answer (score 2):

`ws://192.168.207.84:3000/` is an address on your **private** network.
If your phone is on **3G or other Cellular network**, it won't be able to access your **private** network.

- Verify that your phone connect to the internet via your WiFi network
- Verify that your phone can access this URL using a web browser

If both are true, we might need some more information to better understand the issue.

Comment: http://192.168.207.84:3000/  is working fine on phone  and the meteor application is getting loaded but

ws://192.168.207.84:3000/  is not.